# Connect Azure SQL Server (PaaS) to a VM Scale set

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

How to connect Azure SQL Server (PaaS) to a VM Scale set. The Azure SQL Server has firewall and other network settings. I just want the common procedure like adding a VNet / subnet..

Answer (score 1):

•   With regards to network and firewall configuration, ensure that your **Azure SQL Server has allowed inbound connections and traffic over SQL TCP port 1433 from the Azure VMSS if you are configuring this infrastructure in private, internal mode, i.e., within your specified virtual networks only**.

•   **Connections between the same virtual network are allowed by default, thus if the Azure SQL server and the VMSS are in different virtual networks**, then only the above connections are required. Also, ensure that **outbound as well as the inbound traffic on the VMSS has been allowed on the above said TCP ports in the firewall and the NSG**.

•   Ensure that **SQL Server allows connections over TCP ports, has enabled SQL Server authentication with a SQL login and password with permissions to access the hosted SQL database**.

For more clarification, kindly refer the below documentation link for more details: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/ways-to-connect-to-sql?view=azuresql#connect-to-sql-server-within-a-virtual-network**

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connect-vm-instance-configure?view=azuresql**

[image: Private endpoint]

As above, you can **configure a private endpoint for the Azure SQL Database server and then use the SQL Server Management Studio from the VMSS to access the SQL Database server from it using the private DNS FQDN of the private endpoint over the specified subnet only**.

Similarly, as shown below in the snapshot, the virtual network subnet for the VMSS is also added as a rule in the selected networks section.

[image: Virtual network allow]